# Is it possible to find client details using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-tracking

I need to find website visitors (client) details using only JavaScript/jquery.Is there any way without using third party API?If not possible then any trustful third party API to get client details like machine name(optional),mobile device model name,time stamp etc.

Comment: looking for this ? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp

Comment: try Google analytics

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is is possible. The **window.navigator** object contains information about the client's browser. You can get following details through **window.navigator** object:

1. Official name of the browser.
2. Internal "code" name of the current browser.
3. Version of the browser.
4. Battery charging status.
5. Information about the network connection.
6. Location of the device.
7. Is Java-enabled or not.
8. Preferred language of the user.
9. Current operating system.
10. Platform of the browser.
11. Plugins installed in the browser.
12. And a few others..

There are few non-standard properties as well.
Refer this page on MDN: [Navigator property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Navigator